# Unable to switch background image in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, switch-statement

I"m pretty new to jQuery and I've a question regarding using switch to change the background colour in jQuery. Basically I've got it working to change the colour, however I now want to be able to change the background image of the body to various different images based on on click of the anchors. I've created a js fiddle to explain what I already have : http://tinyurl.com/oqnmqte

Comment: So is your question that you want to extend your function to also change background images. Or instead change background images ?

Comment: @DominicGreen I want to instead change the background image, can I manipulate what I have or do I need to re-write the whole function?

Comment: Na you can use what you already have see my answer bellow, but you may want to consider rewritting and passing the image url through from the markup rather than a number. Then you wont need a switch statement.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at pulling the image from the markup

Comment: No probs ive put a quick simple example in my answer, for pulling through which will still work for images and colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can extend what you have like this

http://jsfiddle.net/q7Cpn/2/

```
function changeBg(currentItem) {
    var bg = 'null';
    switch (+currentItem) {
        case 1 :
            bg = '#FFFFFF';
            break;
        case 2 :
            bg = '#FF6000';
            break;
        case 3 :
            bg = "url('http://www.fascinatingpics.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Google-Logo.png')"
            break;
    }
    $('html').css('background', bg);
}

$('#colour-changer li a').bind('click', function() {
    changeBg(this.id);
    return false;
});
```

A slightly more scalable solution would be to pass the data through from the markup, which will mean you will not need a switch. Ive put a quick example up here . http://jsfiddle.net/q7Cpn/7/

```
<ul id="colour-changer">
        <li><a id="1" class="white" data-bg="#FFFFFF" href="#">White</a></li>
        <li><a id="2" class="grey" data-bg="#FF6000" href="#">Orange</a></li>
        <li><a id="3" class="grey" data-bg="http://www.fascinatingpics.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Google-Logo.png" href="#">Orange</a></li>
    </ul>
```

.

```
    function changeBg(currentItem) {
        var bg = "";

        if (/(jpg|gif|png|JPG|GIF|PNG|JPEG|jpeg)$/.test(currentItem)){
            bg = "url('"+currentItem+"')";
        }else{
            bg = currentItem;
        }
        $('html').css('background', bg);
    }

    $('#colour-changer li a').bind('click', function() {
        changeBg($(this).attr("data-bg"));
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('html').css("background-image", "url(/name.jpg)");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('html').css('backgroundColor', bg);
```

You had "background" in stead of the correct css style "background-color".

In jQuery all css effects that have a '-' in it are replaced by a capital in the following word.

Ex:

CSS:
background-color
jQuery:
backgroundColor

CSS:
margin-left
jQuery:
marginLeft

Comment: The question is how to change background image not the color